# Send as hex in PHP

Tags: php, php-socket

I am struggeling a little to send a hex value to a device connected to my PHP socket server.

I have this code:

```
<?PHP

# 7e hex = 126 decimal

$str1 = "\x7e\x00MyData";
sendToDevice($str1); // works :-)
# will send "~<NUL>MyData" and the device sends expected result back

$dec = 126;
$hex = dechex($dec);
$str2 = $hex . "\x00MyData";
sendToDevice($str2); // does not work :-/
# will send "7eMyData" and the device sends nothing back

$dec = 126;
$hex = dechex($dec);
$str3 = "\x$hex\x00MyData";
sendToDevice($str3); // does not work :-/
# will send "\x7e<NUL>MyData" and the device sends error report back

?>
```

How can I sent it so it works as with **$str1** ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work :-/"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Here's something I noticed. When wrapped in double quotes, PHP seems to evaluate the hex numbers. For example, the output of `print_r("\x7f\x00MyData");` and `print_r('\x7f\x00MyData');` is not the same. Maybe this will help you. Also see http://codepad.org/GbbhYouP.

Comment: Please add the source code of `sendToDevice()`. Otherwise it is just guessing

Comment: Source I am using: [link](http://systemsarchitect.net/multi-threaded-socket-server-in-php-with-fork/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way PHP parses the strings. When PHP parses the first string, it sees the "\x7e" and says "I need to convert this to the character who's code is 7e in hex. In the other scenarios, it sees the "\x", and tries to convert that before it gets the "7e", so it doesn't know what to do.

PHP doesn't parse the strings a second time.

What you need to do in this situation is convert your number to the character representation, rather than the hex code. What you need is the [chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function. You should be able to do something like this:

```
$dec = 127;
$str2 = chr($dec) . "\x00MyData";
sendToDevice($str2);
```

Note that it's skipping the hex conversion altogether. Also note that this only works if your $dec value is <= 255. If you've got higher values, you'll need to create your own function to break it up in to several characters.

Comment: I am not sure if I was misleading in my question, "send as hex" but this was actually exactly what I needed... to send it as a character instead. Now I send the char and I received the expected result back from the connected device.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd approach is not so far away. But a remaining problem is, that the `\x` will be interpeted as an [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) in double quoted strings. Workaround: Use single quotes:

```
$dec = 127;
$hex = dechex($dec);
$str3 = '\x' . $hex . '\x00MyData';
sendToDevice($str3);
```

A simpler solution that does not need `dechex()` would be to use [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) as it has internal support for converting decimal values to hex values. Now it can be even a one-liner:

```
sendToDevice(sprintf('\x%x\x00MyData', $dec));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - see my updated post where I write what I can see it sends to the device. I also did try the single/double quote but it didn't work either. I need it to send the hex value and not the text interpretation.